# I'm running a Minecraft Fabric server. I don't want my admins to be able to use give and similar cheaty commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I'm running a Minecraft Fabric 1.16.3 Tech server. I don't want my admins to be able to use give and similar cheaty commands without de-opping them. Basically, i want to disable `/give`, `/summon` `/fill`, `/setblock` and similar ones. Is there a mod that does this or is there some other way i can do this? Reminder, the server software is **Fabric 1.16.3**. Help appreciated

Comment: Why would you want to not have your admins be able to do that though? If you trust them as admins then you should be able to trust them even with cheaty commands. That's the point of having admins, to have people with that power for management purposes.

Comment: I think that these people probably shouldn’t be opped then, but I still like the question because the question itself is good

Comment: I want my admins to be able to detect people who are hacking, but don't want to give them an unfair advantage over other players. I want the admins to play legitimately without cheating in items

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mod like https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/fabric-server-essentials, or as stated just ensure your mods are trustworthy and will not cheat in items.  Additionally, sometimes admins of servers will spawn items back in to replace ones lost in playerdata corruptions, buggy deaths, and greifs.